# java Selenium how to verify the value of a text

Tags: java, html, selenium, automation

how to check the value of a text within a table. I'm using java and the selenium classes

I would like to verify that the value present in the td is "timetoresponse"

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"IncidentSearch\"]/tbody/tr/td[33]"));
```

below the html code

```
<a tabindex="0" role="button" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="focus" data-placement="auto" data-content="" data-original-title="" title=""></a><td style="">timeToResponse</td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use getText() method on element found to find the text
2. Use java equals method to verify if it is expected text or not
3. You can also use testNG asserts to verify value.

   ```
     WebElement element = 
       driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='IncidentSearch']/tbody/tr/td[33]"));
       if (element.getText().equals("timeToResponse")))
        System.out.println("Match found");
       else 
        System.out.println("Match Not found");
      Assert.assertEquals(element.getText(), "timeToResponse");
   ```

Answer (score 2):

You have used absolute xpath, Which is not recommended in Automation script. As it contains HTML index, And if DOM change with structure this xpath can not work anymore. You should use Relative xpath.

**Relative xpath of the node :  `//a[@title='Title value of this attribute']//td`**

Like wise, you can use any of the attribute of `<a>` tag and locate `<td>`

You can check it by Java equal method,

```
String retrieveText = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@title='Title value of this attribute']//td")).getText();

if(retrieveText.equals("timeToResponse")) {
//User defined message on console
System.out.println("Value match as Expected");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If this test is getting executed via JUnit then you could just use:

`void org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(String message, Object expected, Object actual)`

i.e.

```
assertEquals("timeToResponse Check ....","timeToResponse",driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@title='Title value of this attribute']//td")).getText());
```